# When Don't Keep Activities option on, onSavedInstanceState is giving null in Activity A

Tags: android, state-saving

[Flow Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVEbn.jpg) I am facing a strange issue related to saving the state in Android.
When I turn on Don't Keep Activities option in Android(From Developer Option). Then if I launch Activity B(which launches Fragment B) from Fragment A (launched by Activity A). Then my `onSavedInstance` method is getting called in Fragment A but in `OnCreate` method of Fragment A, I am getting received bundle as null.

And above is inconsistent means sometimes (Specially reproduced when clear the data Android).

In my Activity A in method onSaveInstanceState I have saved my Fragment A with below impl -:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(Bundle,FRAGMENT_TAG,instanceOFFragA);
```

Also in my onCreate I am trying to retrieve the saved Fragment A with below impl -:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    args = savedInstanceState;
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (fragment != null && fragment.getClass().equals(FragA.class)) {
        instanceOfFragA = (FragA) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }
}
```

But in `OnCreate` I am getting instance of Fragment C (which is basically a Registration Fragment which have Login & Register button, Login click will launch LoginActivity which inturn launches LoginFragment. If login get success it calls back on Activity A which launches Fragment A(as login is success)).

Comment: can you post your activity A code?

Comment: @himanshu1496 Basically that is not Activity A but Fragment A. And sorry that is our production code.

Comment: then your question is not clear to me my friend.